# Dynamic Validation in JSF web application

Tags: validation, jsf, design-patterns

We are developing project with JSF as presentation tier.I have set of requirements for which i am searching for suitable pattern.Requirements as below.Please let me know your suggestions

1.Field validations must be configurable.Field can be made mandatory/non mandatory by Admin.So mandatory conditions to be driven
   from Database.
   2.User input data to be validated against value in database
   3.Cross field validation.One dropdown to be validated against value in another dropdown
Am looking for an approach to achieve all the above said conditions.Let me know your thoughts

By any way can we integrate Apache commons validator with JSF2.0

Comment: JSF2.0 provides so many inbuilt validation tags. First please explore them

Answer (score 4):

> *Field can be made mandatory/non mandatory by Admin*

Just use EL in `required` attribute the usual way.

```
<h:inputXxx id="foo" ... required="#{settings.fooRequired}" />
```

---

> *User input data to be validated against value in database*

Just create a custom JSF validator the usual way.

```
<h:inputXxx id="foo" ... validator="fooValidator" />
```

You can even make it dynamic based on applicationwide settings by EL:

```
<h:inputXxx id="foo" ...>
    <f:validator validatorId="#{settings.fooValidator}" />
</h:inputXxx>
```

---

> *Cross field validation. One dropdown to be validated against value in another dropdown*

Just let the EL check the value of another dropdown.

```
<h:selectOneMenu binding="#{menu1}" ... />
<h:selectOneMenu ... required="#{menu1.value == 'foo'} "/>
```

---

> *can we integrate Apache commons validator with JSF2.0*

Just create a custom validator the usual way which in turn invokes any of them.

Comment: Thanks Balusc.Will check out the options specified